# Logging credentials passed to a WCF Web Service

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-client

I have a web service client configured with transport security and Basic clientCredentialType.
The service is using a HTTPS endpoint and I have a difficult to diagnose error. I was trying to add a log to the application that stores the request and response messages, as well as the Credentials passed (at least the username).
For the messages I added a custom Behavior with a MessageInspector.
How can I log the credentials also? Is there any extension point in WCF to do this? Any other suggestion?
Thanks

Edit: The error I am getting is this:

```
[NotSupportedException: This method is not supported by this class.]
System.Net.BasicClient.Lookup(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials credentials) +2544984
System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials) +304
System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo) +7949046
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth() +269
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e) +126
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception) +185
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse() +75
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData) +562

[WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +7865220
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +99

[CommunicationException: An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4729827
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
...Application code from here on...
```

It is a web application that is working correctly in DEV but throws this error in QA. The code is the same and the user is valid in both environments.

The binding configuration is:

```
<binding name="CommonBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what method of user/pass authentication are you using?

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx

I believe you could do this in an IAuthorizationPolicy

Comment: As I understand that is in the server side. I want to do this at the client side as the web services are not WCF and I don't have much control over them.

Comment: so you want to log the user identity on the client side? is it x.509 or user pass? you could get it out of the clientCredentials behavior.

Comment: It is user/pass. Do you have an example of how can I use clientCredentials behavior for this? I want to capture the effective user and pass being sent, not the configured ones (anyway, they are set in code)

Comment: if it is just user/pass you could get away with implementing a custom message encoder and extracting them from the message via xpath. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx I would say there is probably a more elegant way which does not inspect the message, but the only way to know for sure what is sent is in the encoder